# Shall we use wrap_content or static width and height for images that are sliced properly?

Tags: android

I have some images sliced for all types of resolutions (mdpi, hdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi or sw360dp, sw320dp etc.) provided by a UX/UI designer. So the question is: shall we set the image as wrap_content with layout_height and layout_width, or shall we using static dimensions for it?

Case 1 Example:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Case 2 Example:

```
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
```

Comment: I think that your Friend A is correct. If you have enough image type for each screen you should use wrap_content :)

Comment: I think that you, your friends and @LubomirBabev were too lazy to read the [official docs](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html).

Comment: Thank for your official docs. I didn't know about that :) I will read it now.